# identify which application is calling a DLL

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, dll

I have a DLL (vb.net) which is used by several applications.

I have referenced the DLL in several .net applications (using visual studio 2015).

I need to identify which application is invoking functions.

ex:

```
Public Sub xpto ()

if (application A) then

end if

If (application B) then

end if


End Sub
```

How can I do this in a dll?

Comment: Looking for oracles like this is a Very Bad Idea.  You are overlooking application C, shows up a year from now.  And unit tests, guaranteed you'll need them some rainy day when too many of these hacks blow up badly.  Give the method an argument to let it do its proper job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get the first other assembly calling your function.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of `GetCallingAssembly()` as suggested.

This call will help identify you **the actual process** running calling your library instead of the library immediately calling your assembly.

> Gets the process executable in the default application domain. In
>   other application domains, this is the first executable that was
>   executed by ExecuteAssembly(String).

Applied to your scenario, you would have something like this:

```
Public Sub xpto ()

' Grabs the entry assembly.
Dim entryAssembly as Assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()

' Grabs its name
Dim entryAssemblyName as AssemblyName = entryAssembly.GetName()

    If (entryAssemblyName.Name == ApplicationA) Then

    End If

    If (entryAssemblyName.Name == ApplicationB) Then

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Careful with that, because the "entry assembly" in unit tests will all be the same, the unit test host application, no matter which project you're unit testing.

Comment: @Blindy Oh! that's definitely true. I did not want to look at the potential design issues that such needs will raise (i.e. finding out who is calling a given library).